# Visual Basic - MySql connection is failing on another computer

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am having a problem with a program of mine.  It is a chat program with a login system using MySQL.  I downloaded MySQL Connector Net 6.9.6 and I am using it with Visual Basic.  When I run the program it works perfectly (both in debug and release mode) and it connects to my MySQL database.

However, when my friend tried to do it but he couldn't connect to the database.  Do I need to put a library file within the program or he should download MySQL Connector Net too?

Comment: so in debug mode it does not work but in release it does ?

Comment: no it works the same on all but on another person's computer it doesn't

Comment: so you are basically chatting to yourself :>

Comment: here is my question... if any old user out there wants to chat, and you have a **server**, why would any **client** need the mysql or sql-server connector / lib / driver? Why wouldn't they just make calls to php or IIS ? Everyone is happily chatting thru port 80 and polling. VB socket programming, port 80, no native calls to db from client directly. let the server handle that [the webserver]

Comment: Are your friend trying to connect to your chat from a remote computer or in your internal LAN?

Comment: Perhaps a firewall issue : has a firewall exception been set for MySQL server port on client PC ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your program works on your local computer(i mean the software works in the same environment where the database engine is running).

If you want to let your friend connects to the Mysql Server, then you should create an user for your friend pointing to the remote ip address of your friend, like this:

1. So if your friend have the following public ip: `200.28.145.128`
2. You in your mysql console, have to write the following command:

   `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON yourChatDataBase.* TO remoteuser@200.28.145.128 IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';`
3. Now your friend should haves to modify your connection string with that data in order to connect to your mysql server from his remote computer(just him).
   `

Comment: Im sorry for this late answer I was trying to remember my acc password because it is on gmail, however the problem is that the MySQL server is not in my computer, and Im not running the program in that MySQL host computer!